# Restore small section of OSB behind inner wall

Tags: repair, walls, osb

Repairing Oriented strand board (OSB)
finishing joinery wood-repair
I cut out a small 4" x 5" piece of Oriented strand board out of a wall. I saved this cut out piece so I can re-attach it.

When I put the piece back in the hole I cut, what do I use to re-attach it so it stays stable? (so it won't fall back or forward out of the hole.)
If this can be done, what do I use to fill in the crack of air that will be around this piece that was cut out, after, it is re-attached?

Comment: What is that first sentence? Please revise for clarity.

Comment: What purpose does the OSB serve? Is this exterior sheathing or something inside the framing? Please add more detail about your wall's construction. Photos would be great.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, we'll need more info before we have any chance of helping you. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Is this OSB behind drywall or panelling? (Fifty years ago when plywood was relatively cheap my parents had a house built in south Louisiana by a builder who sheathed all interior walls with 1/2 in plywood and put 1/2 in drywall over that. )

Answer (score 2):

When I have a small hole in a wall I will use a strip of wood (1x1/2x~8”). Slip the piece into the hole and using screws. Put at least 1 screw in each end of the board. I put one on each side of the hole then put the piece in and screw the square to the strips I just installed. I have even used paint stir sticks when making this kind of repair in drywall, but for plywood or OSB like something a bit stronger. I have used silicone on the wood to seal the patch at the seams. This would be the best advice I can offer with the information provided.

Comment: Thank you, Ed Beal.  That'll work.